# If X is a subset of a complete boolean algebra, must there be a finite $Y \subset X$ s.t. sup(Y) = sup(X)?

Tags: boolean-algebra

The question came up when I was trying to prove the compactness of the stone space S(B) of a complete boolean algebra B. Using only the basic facts regarding ultrafilters and boolean algebras, I cannot seem to find an answer.

Thank you very much, in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The property in title seems require compactness. However, it seems not every complete boolean algebra is compact. there is a counterexample.
Let $B=\wp(\omega)$, $X=\omega$. Note that $n=\{0,1,...,n-1\}$.

Then $\sup(X)=\bigcup(X)=\omega$, but for every finite $Y\subseteq X$, $\sup(Y)$ is definitely a finite number.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yep I guess my approach was wrong. Would it be correct if I said that, given a subset _X_ of _B_ s.t. X is pairwise compatible (every pair has a non-zero meet), then there exists a filter of _B_ containing _X_?

Comment: @JohnToh Sure, $B$ itself is. Moreover $\{z \in B|\bigwedge Y \le z  \mbox{ for some finite collection } Y \mbox{ of } X\}$ is the smallest one and which is also proper.